# confluent schema registry create schema with id value other than 1

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

Currently we are using camus schema registry and
We are migrating from camus schema registry to confluent schema registry.
camus has latest id with value 22.
Can I create schema in confluent with the id 22 directly other than 1.

I looked over documentation but it always creates schema with id 1.

Answer (score 0):

Each unique schema gets its own ID.

You'd need to create 21 unique dummy schemas in order to reach ID 22, since it cannot be done directly.